# How to preserve "itemize" format when converting mathematica notebook to a latex file?

Tags: stylesheet, latex

When I convert a Mathematica notebook containing following cells with "itemize" format to a latex file
[image]

these cells become raw text format like this:

```
probability densities

expectations and covariances

def: covariance of x and y

Bayesian probabilities

frequentist view and Bayesian view

posterior $\propto $ likelihood $\times $ prior

One advantage of the Bayesian viewpoint is that the \pmb{ inclusion of prior knowledge} arises naturally, so the conclusion would be less extreme

Gaussian distribution

maximum likelihood approach

to determine parameters $\mu $ and $\sigma $, we define a likelihood function to be the probability of drawing the data set given a set of specific
$\mu $ and $\sigma $, and then decide parameters to maximize this function.

one problem: underestimate $\sigma $

curve fitting revisited
```

How could I preserve all itemize formats in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: My advice is: if you want LaTeX in the end then write LaTeX. Don't write a notebook and hope to be able to convert it later. The feature to add bullet points in notebooks came a long time after updates to the TeX converter have all but stopped.